# How do I add a legend to a facet in ggtree's `facet_plot`?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtree

I am using `facet_plot()` to add a barplot with trait values next to the tips of my tree. I need there to be a legend for the barplot, but could not find in the [documentation](https://yulab-smu.github.io/treedata-book/) or in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722055/add-legend-into-ggtree-ggplot-r) how to do that. It seems that `facet_plot()` makes this a bit trickier.

Here is my code:

```
library(ggtree)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggstance) # for horizontal versions of geoms

# create some random tree and trait data
tree <- rtree(5)
traits <- tibble(
  node  = paste0("t", rep(1:5, 4)),
  trait = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 5),
  value = rnorm(n = 20, mean = 10, sd = 2))

# tree plot with barplot facet
treeplot <- ggtree(tree) + geom_tiplab(align = T)
facet_plot(treeplot,
           panel = "Trait",
           data = traits,
           geom = geom_barh,
           mapping = aes(x = value, fill = trait),
           stat = "identity")
```

[image: Random tree with trait data mapped to tips]

I've tried to add `+ guides(fill = guide_legend())` or `+ scale_fill_discrete()`, but to no avail.

How can I add a legend to the Trait facet? (And, in extension, to any additional facet?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add `theme(legend.position="bottom")` to get desired plot.

```
facet_plot(treeplot,
           panel = "Trait",
           data = traits,
           geom = geom_barh,
           mapping = aes(x = value, fill = trait),
           stat = "identity", show.legend = TRUE) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the legend is for the tree (and not the annotation). Works neither with `facet_plot` nor `geom_facet`.

Comment: Addendum: actually works, but users trying this, please be warned, if you're going to use `ggtree::facet_widths`, locate the legend properly first beforehand.